# Not able to find pre-defined sass variables in Jekyll project

Tags: ruby, sass, jekyll

I'm new the Jeykll and Sass and have a quick question.  Within the pre-built theme when starting a new project, where are these variables defined?

I can't seem to find them aware through out the build.
This is in the _sass/layout.scss directory.

```
 */
.site-header {
    border-top: 5px solid $grey-color-dark;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $grey-color-light;
    min-height: 56px;

    // Positioning context for the mobile navigation icon
    position: relative;
}

.site-title {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 56px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: left;

    &,
    &:visited {
        color: $grey-color-dark;
    }
}

.site-nav {
    float: right;
    line-height: 56px;

    .menu-icon {
        display: none;
    }

    .page-link {
        color: $text-color;
        line-height: $base-line-height;

        // Gaps between nav items, but not on the first one
        &:not(:first-child) {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    }

    @include media-query($on-palm) {
        position: absolute;
        top: 9px;
        right: 30px;
        background-color: $background-color;
        border: 1px solid $grey-color-light;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: right;

        .menu-icon {
            display: block;
            float: right;
            width: 36px;
            height: 26px;
            line-height: 0;
            padding-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;

            > svg {
                width: 18px;
                height: 15px;

                path {
                    fill: $grey-color-dark;
                }
            }
        }

        .trigger {
            clear: both;
            display: none;
        }

        &:hover .trigger {
            display: block;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .page-link {
            display: block;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
    }
}



/**
 * Site footer
 */
.site-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid $grey-color-light;
    padding: $spacing-unit 0;
}

.footer-heading {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: $spacing-unit / 2;
}

.contact-list,
.social-media-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.footer-col-wrapper {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: $grey-color;
    margin-left: -$spacing-unit / 2;
    @extend %clearfix;
}

.footer-col {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: $spacing-unit / 2;
    padding-left: $spacing-unit / 2;
}

.footer-col-1 {
    width: -webkit-calc(35% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
    width:         calc(35% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

.footer-col-2 {
    width: -webkit-calc(20% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
    width:         calc(20% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

.footer-col-3 {
    width: -webkit-calc(45% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
    width:         calc(45% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

@include media-query($on-laptop) {
    .footer-col-1,
    .footer-col-2 {
        width: -webkit-calc(50% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
        width:         calc(50% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
    }

    .footer-col-3 {
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
        width:         calc(100% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
    }
}

@include media-query($on-palm) {
    .footer-col {
        float: none;
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
        width:         calc(100% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
    }
}



/**
 * Page content
 */
.page-content {
    padding: $spacing-unit 0;
}

.page-heading {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.post-list {
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;

    > li {
        margin-bottom: $spacing-unit;
    }
}

.post-meta {
    font-size: $small-font-size;
    color: $grey-color;
}

.post-link {
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
}



/**
 * Posts
 */
.post-header {
    margin-bottom: $spacing-unit;
}

.post-title {
    font-size: 42px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 1;

    @include media-query($on-laptop) {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
}

.post-content {
    margin-bottom: $spacing-unit;

    h2 {
        font-size: 32px;

        @include media-query($on-laptop) {
            font-size: 28px;
        }
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 26px;

        @include media-query($on-laptop) {
            font-size: 22px;
        }
    }

    h4 {
        font-size: 20px;

        @include media-query($on-laptop) {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> **Notice:** Jekyll has since been updated, its default theme, `minima`, is now in a separate gem, and the definitions are [there, in `_sass/minima.scss`](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_sass/minima.scss).

---

<s>[**Look at this**, with relative path to site root in default Jekyl site `css/main.scss`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/site_template/css/main.scss). There they are. *After all the definitions, imports and processing*, there will be `css/main.css` in the resulting site.</s>

Everything in `_sass` is just for importing into **real** assets that will be converted to CSS. The difference between Sass/SCSS files in `_sass` and everywhere else is that files from `_sass` are not compiled directly, but rather just lay where they are and wait to be imported. Every possibly reusable piece of Sass should be in `_sass`, that's what Sass partials and this system overall is designed for. This is especially useful if you use a lot of Sass libraries ([like I do, and it's still a mess](https://github.com/D-side/dside/tree/master/_sass)) and don't want them to be modified in order to be put into your assets.

All the other files (not in `_sass`), however, will be processed into corresponding `*.css` files, and in order to distinguish files for processing, Jekyll requires such files to have a **YAML front-matter**, usually **empty**.

```
---
---

// Sass code here
```

*(I used to utilize Liquid for embedding variables in Sass, but [that feature vanished after some updates](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2573), so now non-empty YFM in assets is of no use now).*

Comment: I'm....actually a little confused by this. I mean, I can see the sass variables on GitHub. But I don't get why that part of the project was not cloned when I pulled it onto my local. Help?

Comment: @sabaeus this template is copied over when running `jekyll new sitename`. Did you do that?

Comment: I did. I get it now. The exact directory structure shown on the GitHub page is not copied onto my local when I run `jekyll new sitename`. Folders like "bin" "lib" and "script" are missing from my directory, but their functionality is preserved. I'm assuming that code is stored in my gem installation directory to keep people like me from accidentally ruining it.

Comment: @sabaeus uhm, the template is actually in `lib/site_template`.

Comment: The _look at this_ link is broken btw.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini sorry for the delay! I took a year off Stack Exchange :) Fixed it.